# давайте обсудим visual studio code и TypeScript

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

оглавление

1. среда разработки **[VSCode]**
2. **TypeScrip**
3. конфиги [tsconfig.json] [jsconfig.json]

---

## 1. среда разработки **[VSCode]**

upd: @AK, был создан отдельный вопрос для этого обсуждения
[Объединить метки Visual Studio Code](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7005)

**предлагаю:**
[VSCode] = [visual-studio-code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)
[vscode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) - перекинуть и удалить  (upd:не знал, что метки только в нижнем регистре)
[VSCode] - основная метка

**обоснование:**
считаю термин **VSCode** устоявшимся, в том числе в русскоязычном сообществе
https://www.google.ru/search?q=VSCode&lr=lang_ru

> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging
>   Например, [css] подойдет лучше, чем [cascading-style-sheets].

## 2. **TypeScript**

**предлагаю:**
[ts][d.ts] слинковать с [typescript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)

**обоснование:**
у [js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) есть линк с [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

ts = js но с типами
d.ts - это только типы, могут использоваться совместно с чистым js НО при этом они остаются частью TypeScript

```
| язык         | расширения файлов   |
|--------------|---------------------|
| [TypeScrip]  | [ts] [d.ts] [tsx]   |
| [JavaScrip]  | [js] [jsx]          |
| ------------ | ------------------- |
| react        | tsx/jsx             |
| ------------ | ------------------- |
| язык         | расширения файлов   |
```

## 3. конфиги [tsconfig.json] [jsconfig.json]

сомнительно, но **подумать** стоит:
добавить [tsconfig.json] [jsconfig.json] и связать с чем?

- [TypeScrip]
- [VSCode]

https://www.google.ru/search?q=tsconfig.json&lr=lang_ru
https://www.google.ru/search?q=jsconfig.json&lr=lang_ru

по хорошему, *tsconfig.json* относится к TS, тут всё понятно
а вот с *jsconfig.json* непонятки используется компилятором tsc(TS) и редактором VSCode

---

отойдя от темы, (: c ?эстонским акцентом) как это будет по русски "**types**" ?

Comment: На будущее: делайте отдельные топики, у вас тут три разных темы, причём решение по некоторым очевидно, а по некоторым спорно.

Comment: @AK нуууу, дааа, предполагалось два вопроса в одном 1 и 2 а вот третий в процессе родился, да и не понятно куда отнеси и вообще надо ли..

Comment: Метки надо писать как `[tag:имя-метки]`. Дальше - непонятно, что и почему.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хмм, не замечал что все метки строчные

Comment: @Qwertiy а что не понятно, какой пункт?

Comment: Я предлагаю удалить вопрос, чтобы разделить голосование по отдельным вопросам. Как минимум, есть неоднозначность какую метку считать основной для VS Code - и тут будет как минимум будет два ответа только по этому вопросу. А по другим меткам? Давайте не будем захламлять тему!!

Comment: Ок, поскольку автор вопроса не согласен с тем, что вопрос стоит переделать - а я не хочу полностью менять текстовку вопроса, то предлагаю проголосовать за закрытие. Если наберётся ещё 4 голоса - обязуюсь как минимум создать новую тему под visual studio (а может и под остальные тоже). Формулировка закрытия - "вопрос слишком общий"

Comment: красный день календаря - вечер после пятницы. Автор, тоесть Я. не против закрытия, правки, разделения вопроса. Однако! хочу привести довод против этого: не все достаточно хорошо понимаю аспекты, описанные в этом вопросе, а если их ещё и разнести на три - четыре - то непонимание только увеличится.

Comment: Да никто ничего не закрывает. Группировать связанные обсуждения конечно можно и нужно.  Другое дело, что сформулировать положения можно было чуть более четко

Comment: Создал отдельную тему про [visual studio](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7005/213987)

Answer (score 1):

> предлагаю:
>
> [VSCode] = visual-studio-code

+

> язык         | расширения файлов   |
>
> |--------------|---------------------|
>
> | [TypeScrip]  | [ts] [d.ts] [tsx]

Ну так-то, расширение файлов ts это не только typescript, а еще, к примеру, MPEG2 Transport Stream. Так что не надо тут ничего делать.

> сомнительно, но подумать стоит:
>
> добавить [tsconfig.json] [jsconfig.json] и связать с чем?

Если вы считаете, что нужно создать какую-то метку, просто добавьте ее в вопросы через механизм предлагаемых правок (или задайте свои вопросы с ней). Спрашивать на мете не надо. Если метка окажется плохой, снести не проблема.

Comment: хочу вот метку создать, опережая stackoverflow `Napa.JS` только вот ещё не придумал как бы грамотно вопрос оформить : ) А что скажете по поводу types=пипы=d.ts ведь это нужная штука, но сформулировать её сложно. на руСО есть два НЕПОНЯТНЫХ тега [tag:типы] [tag:типы-данных]

Comment: @qwabra Да, конечно они тоже должны быть синонимизированы.  На SO полно меток,нуждающихся в синонимизации, просто эффективного механизма для осуществления этого нет.

Comment: не, я про текущий контекст TypeScript и его файлы с расширением `d.ts`

Comment: @qwabra Метки [d.ts] сейчас не существует. Если вы считаете, что она нужна, как я уже сказал, можете создать. Но синонимизировать ее с [типы] не надо, так как последняя применима к разным понятиям в разных языках программирования.

Comment: я в принципе не пойму как в русском языке использовать types, какой термин будет корректен(типы как-то не очень). Возвращаясь к вашему ответу `d.ts` это файл типов для TS, вот, поэтому я и предлагаю его создать и синонимизировать с TypeScript. вооот. прошу прощения за многА букАф.

Comment: @qwabra Создавать метку, только для того чтобы ее синонимизировать, обычно не нужно. Если ее кто-то создаст, тогда и будем разбираться. Типы и types - уже синонимы, кстати.