# Объединить метки Visual Studio Code

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

На сайте сейчас [76 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) с меткой [visual-studio-code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) и [8 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) с меткой [vscode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode).

Давайте их синонимизируем?

Непонятно, правда, какой вариант сделать основным синонимом: предлагаю провести голосование.

Делаю два основных варианта: для [visual-studio-code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) и для [vscode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode), эти варианты общие и если кому-то захочется дописать аргументы "за" этот вариант — можно дописывать.

Также если кому-то захочется высказать особое мнение — пишет отдельный вариант.

Comment: Прошёл год, а метки так и объединяют

Comment: @L.F.C. Посмотрел - вижу, сообщество весьма чётко определилось в голосовании, так что уже можно и обьединить.

Comment: Это конечно не первый и не последний вопрос по объединению меток, но такое ощущение, что это никому не надо вообще. Найдеться 2-3 активиста и всё катится на их энтузиазме, пока у них есть силы бороться. Может необходимо в сообществе какие-то временные рамки для подобных действий задать?

Answer (score 10):

Предлагаю сделать основной меткой [visual-studio-code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)

Аргументы "за":

- По названию тега хорошо понятно, о чём эта метка (выгодно по сравнению с сокращением vscode, пусть и устоявшимся)
- Вопросов по этой метке больше (пусть по историческим причинам, но всё проще поменять 8 вопросов, чем 76)
- Эта метка является основной на en.so

Comment: Длинновато получается...

Comment: Эта метка является основной на en.so.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Пусть хотя бы неделю-другую повисит опрос. Начали в выходной день, когда на сайте почти никого - и вы хотите за сутки всё быстро решить. Не стоит так торопиться.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, я вообще ничего не делал.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, сейчас [tag:vscode] отдельно, а [tag:vs-code] = [tag:visual-studio-code]

Comment: @Qwertiy Значит есть смысл доделать, раз [tag:vscode] синоним.

Comment: @Qwertiy Сможете синонимизировать к [tag:visual-studio-code]? Здесь 10+ голосов за, что для меты в такой специфической теме почти максимум.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать основной меткой [vscode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode)

Аргументы "за":

- Название краткое, удобно набирать - и в сообществе программистов вполне устоявшееся
- У этой метки преимущество в том, что с неё могут начинаться более длинные метки (есть на en.so): [vscode-extensions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-extensions), [vscode-settings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-settings).

Comment: У этой метки преимущество в том, что с неё могут начинаться более длинные метки (есть на en.so): vscode-extensions, vscode-settings.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не [vs-code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-code)?

Вроде в соответствии с правилами тут должен быть дефис между словами.

Comment: гениально, я за )

Answer (score -3):

## мне всё равно

после того, как узнал, что метки **только в нижнем регистре**

---

словосочетание `visual studio` имеет ряд недостатков

1. все думают что это редактор для windows, редактор же VSCode **является кроссплатформенным**
2. ассоциируется с microsoft платностью закрытостью большим весом итд итп

---

доводы за VSCode приведённые мной в этом вопросе
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/7003

## 1. среда разработки **[VSCode]**

**предлагаю:**
[VSCode] = [visual-studio-code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)
[VSCode] - основная метка

**обоснование:**
считаю термин **VSCode** устоявшимся, в том числе в русскоязычном сообществе
https://www.google.ru/search?q=VSCode&lr=lang_ru

> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging
>   Например, [css] подойдет лучше, чем [cascading-style-sheets].

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо так много излишнего форматирования, читать сложно.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, я за правки, но то что вы сделали - это правка цитат, в том числе из документации.