# Объединить все метки связанные с Visual Studio в одну

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

На сайте идет активное обсуждение объединения меток связанных с братской версией Visual Studio, [а именно Visual Studio Code](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7005/220571). И я обеими руками за, так как их обилие иногда вводит в ступор.

Перечитав этот вопрос, я вспомнил, что каждый раз редактируя вопросы, натыкаюсь на различные метки, связанные с Visual Studio разных версий (годов).

Есть такие как: [visual-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), [visual-studio-2010](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010), [visual-studio-2013](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013), [visual-studio-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015), [vs2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs2015), [visual-studio-2017](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017). Это только те, которые я обнаружил сразу. По факту, это же одно и то же.

**Первый вариант**, я думаю такой, что есть необходимость оставить только одну, которая именуется [visual-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), по нескольким причинам:

- 1,605 вопросов с данной меткой (на момент просмотра);
- более короткое название;
- уже имеет полное описание;

**Второй вариант** ничего не объединять, но тогда вырисовывается еще пару вопросов.
Как быть с описанием меток разных версий Visual Studio?
Описывать их, или в этом нет необходимости? Если описывать, то как?
Если ответы позитивные, предположу, что необходимо описать изменения, которые появились с новой версией (возможно, я ошибаюсь, если это так, исправьте меня, или предложите свои варианты).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не согласен. Visual Studio разных годов могут иметь специфичные проблемы для каждой версии. На enSO метки специфических версий существуют без проблем. Что действительно надо синонимизировать, так это метки специфических версий. В данном случае, нужно сделать [vs2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs2015) синонимом к метке [visual-studio-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015).

Comment: Эти уже синонимы

Comment: Старые версии будут отмирать, одна за другой, со временем, а цепочка из меток будет все длиннее и длиннее... В вопросах, большинство, как правило, указывают какая у них версия, если это так, тогда какой в этом смысл? Понятно, что для разных версий разные проблемы. Но суть, одна и та же. Всегда можно уточнить, какая версия, это ж не проблема.  И при вашем варианте, тогда придется описывать одинаково, много однообразных меток.

Comment: @VladSpirin А почему вы тогда не поднимете этот вопрос для всех меток? Чтобы для всех версий любой среды разработки/технологии/языка программирования специфические версии были синонимом основной метки среды разработки/технологии/языка программирования? И как тогда спрашивать вопросы для специфических версий? А уточнение версии лучше меткой, чем комментарием, так как люди должны приходить сюда из поисковиков и находить свои решения.

Comment: Просто данная мне знакома, в вопросе я вроде описал, что редактирую вопросы и смотрю, о чем люди пишут, от сюда и вывод. Насчет прям всех, я думаю вам никто на ресурсе на ваш вопрос не ответит, он уж слишком абстрактный. Для выяснения всех вот таких подводных камней и поднял обсуждение. У вас своя позиция и она правильная, у меня своя, и она тоже правильная. Тут нет плохих.

Comment: @VladSpirin Я тоже разбираюсь в Visual Studio. Работал с ней с ещё с версии Visual Studio.NET (которая 2003-го года) и успел попробовать каждую. И знаю насколько она эволюционировала за эти годы. И мне кажется ваш подход неудачным. Это же можно всё сделать для версий чего угодно, почему нет? Но тогда пропадёт специфика версий. А какой плюс вашего решения? Уменьшение кол-ва меток? А ради чего?

Comment: Частично вы меня убедили. Голосую (на данный момент) за ваш вариант. Хотя надо еще посмотреть, что кто, думает об этом. Возможно, ваш вариант будет оптимальным и мы больше не вернемся к данному вопросу.

Comment: Я сижу на Visual studio ещё со времен шестой версии. Отдельные метки под каждую студию - это правильный подход, не надо лепить в единую метку разные выпуски.

Comment: Сижу на Visual studio с 2003. Я сомневаюсь, что кто-то сможет в наши дни разбираться в их тонкостях и различиях. Делать метки по версиям считаю лишним. Вопросов применительно к самой среде мало, нет смысла создавать метки по каждой.

Comment: @Suvitruf Так они уже созданы и используются. Отличия в них точно присутствуют, иногда их если пользуешься невозможно не замечать. Поэтому не согласен. Версионность в таких вещах очень нужна. Проблемы и подходы иногда специфичны для опредленной версии или версий.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ну вот увидите вы вопрос с меткой [tag:vs], или [tag:vs2016]. Вы же в любом случае зайдёте, да? Я к тому, что это лишний информационный шум. Но да, мнение у каждого своё. Я лично даже разницы между 2016 и 2017 не назову сейчас, хотя каждый день студию использую.

Comment: @Suvitruf А 2016й не существует. Только 2015 и 2017. И между ними разница огромная, если в них работать профессионально.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ну что значит "работать профессионально"? тим фаундейшн или ещё что? Не знаю, я в Студии сижу только потому что лучше редактора для Unity3d нет. Если бы была возможность, то я бы лучше Eclipse к Unity прикрутил.

Comment: @Suvitruf Ну я имел ввиду по несколько часов в день на протяжении нескольких лет. Если бы вы работали профессионально, то знали бы что vs2016 не существует. Я просто удивлён тем, что вы сказали "vs2016" и не видите разницы между версиями, хотя они просто колоссальны. И из версии к версии изменения иногда просто тотальны, как, к примеру, между vs 2010 и 2008, 2012 и 2010, 2015 и 2013. И именно поэтому эти метки очень нужны для указания специфики.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov какие изменение для меня как разработчика игр там были? Никаких. Ну и да, именно игры я пишу последние 3 года каждый день в Студии. До этого раньше на C++ там писал.

Comment: Раньше были изменения, когда под Win писал, когда WPF и т.п. появились. Но сейчас я даже уже не вспомню, в какой версии это было.

Comment: @Suvitruf Во-первых, метки же не только для вас, а для всех. Не только разработчики игр пользуются VS, там ещё есть намного большая аудитория веб-разработчиков (ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core), разработчиков мобильных приложений (Xamarin), декстоп-разработчиков (WinForms/WPF/UWP) и кучу-кучу кого.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov так решение не за мной. Я считаю, что это лишние теги, вы считаете, что они могут быть полезными. Сообщество решит как лучше )

Comment: @Suvitruf Во-вторых, есть фичи которые затронут очень многих: к примеру установщик поменялся: он полностью переписан с нуля и у него кардинально другой интерфейс. Поэтому вполне легально было бы спросить насчёт: как удалить, как установить/доустановить, как использовать такой-то компонент. Ещё пример: Live Unit Testing. Это фича многим бы разработчикам пригодилась, поэтому вопросы связанные с ней тоже могли иметь место быть. И так далее, не хочется всё перечислять.

Answer (score 0):

> Второй вариант ничего не объединять, но тогда вырисовывается еще пару вопросов.
> Как быть с описанием меток разных версий Visual Studio?
> Описывать их, или в этом нет необходимости? Если описывать, то как?
>
> Если ответы позитивные, предположу, что необходимо описать изменения, которые появились с новой версией (возможно, я ошибаюсь, если это так, исправьте меня, или предложите свои варианты).

"*Используйте данную метку для вопросов по Visual Studio, касающихся особенностей версии (...). Вопрос также должен содержать метку [visual-studio]* "

Да, в полное описании можно вставить краткий перечень изменений в новой версии.